# Storing Partition Keys on CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The concept is very straight away. Not difficulty to understand. But I can't find some practical examples... I've this json...

```
{
    "agendaId": "688c99bc-c756-4b8f-9c39-60246c0ea66e",
    "postId": "f07f16e5-e7d6-441e-bc1d-82ac671e0f63",
    "name": "john doe"
}
```

And I defined this partition: /agendaId/postId

And then I inserted the item.

But I can't see any data on my CosmosDB Container Browser on the column of the partition key - I just can see the autogenerated Id...is this expected ?

[image]

Comment: are you using hierarchical partition key? how are you passing the PK?

Comment: Well..It's the keys defined when you create your container whose default is "/id". And I am not passing the key..I am using the portal to add the data directly via portal

Comment: Well it does not work that way, read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys?tabs=net-v3%2Cbicep

Answer (score 1):

`/agendaId/postId` means that the value is **nested**. The JSON to match that definition should be:

```
{
    "agendaId": {
            "postId": "f07f16e5-e7d6-441e-bc1d-82ac671e0f63",
    },

    "name": "john doe"
}
```

The `/` on the definition defines the level of nesting, so `/attr1/attr2/attr3` would mean that the value is in `attr3` that exists in `attr2` which exists in `attr1`:

```
{
    "attr1": {
        "attr2": {
            "attr3": "the value"
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, if you used, for example `/agendaId` is just the first level of attributes, or `/postId`. Both would pick up the value of the attributes in your document.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey

[image: Snapshot of a text explaining the concept of nested from the linked document]